# Unable to include a header-only library in ROS

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have the following project structure:

```
utils 
 include
   utils 
    image_utils.h
 CMakelists.txt
 package.xml
graph
 src
  graph.cpp
 CMakelists.txt
 package.xml
```

I am trying to use `image_utils.h` in `graph.cpp`.

The `CMakelists` inside utils looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(utils)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp 
)
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)
```

And in the `CMakelists` inside graph i call `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)` as seen below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(pose_graph)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs cv_bridge utils)

find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS utils)
add_executable(graph src/graph.cpp)
target_link_libraries(graph ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} utils)
```

The `package.xml` of graph has the following relevant tag:

```
<depend>utils</depend>
```

My error message is:

```
graph.cpp:12:10: fatal error: utils/image_utils.h: No such file or directory
 #include "utils/image_utils.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @user There is no top-level CMakelists.txt file, but I included the rest of CMakelists.txt from my graph project now

Comment: I would normally do an `add_library(...)` in the `utils` CMakeLists.txt and then link that to your `pose_graph` target. But I don't know if that is what you want

Comment: @revision#3: You still need to fix your repro. The config is still inconsistant with the error.

Comment: How do you expect the graph project to know about the utils project in your `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... utils)`? Have you built and installed it and hinted CMake where you installed it at? Where have you built it and where have you installed it to?

Comment: @user I used `catkin_package()` and `install` in the `CMakelists` of utils. All my relevant files are shown above. If something is missing, please advice me to what I should add. I am not very familiar with CMake.

Comment: Have you actually [run the install step with `cmake --install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project)? Show the commands you use to configure, build, and install the utils project. And again, fix your [mre]: make the config and error message consistent.

Comment: @user The config and error message is consistent. Maybe you should read the title of my post and the tags I use. This is a ROS project. `cmake --install` is not used. I use catkin to build it.

Comment: show your package.xml files then.

Comment: @user updated with the only line I believe is relevant

Comment: great. If you really want to help people help you, though, provide a real [mre].

Comment: @user I don't see what else is missing. Do you want me to upload my whole project here?

Comment: @ignacio thanks, that is what I want. However I got an error in my include statement when I tried that: `Can't find utils/image_utils.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Here are my `CMakelists` files:

utils:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(utils)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)
```

graph:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(pose_graph)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs cv_bridge utils)

find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS utils)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(graph src/graph.cpp)

target_link_libraries(graph ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your folder structure to `utils/include/utils/image_utils.h` and then also add an `add_library(...)` call in your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: I tried this (updated my question with the details). Now I get the error `graph.cpp:12:10: fatal error: utils/image_utils.h: No such file or directory
 #include "utils/image_utils.h"`

Comment: use `<utils/image_utils.h>` instead of `"utils/image_utils.h"`, as the header is from an outside package

Comment: still the same error: `fatal error: utils/image_utils.h: No such file or directory
 #include <utils/image_utils.h>`

Comment: try calling `include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )` after 
`catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS utils)`

Comment: Sorry, which `CMakelists` file should this be in? Since I don't call `catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS utils)` anywhere

Comment: you do in `pose_graph`

Comment: Still the same issue